# bson.errors.InvalidDocument: Cannot encode object: True

Tags: python, python-2.7, pymongo

I got an error when inserting a document in Mongo using python.

```
    document = {u'Status': 'Active',
     u'Installation': {u'IsFrugal': True,  u'IsFeatureSet': True,  u'IsEvolving': True, u'IsAffordable': True}, 
      u'AutoList': [u'IsFeatureSet', u'IsAffordable', u'IsFrugal'] 
    }
```

TraceBack Error is

```
    C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pymongo-2.5.1_-py2.7-win32.egg\pymongo\collection.
    py:357: RuntimeWarning: couldn't encode - reloading python modules and trying ag
    ain. if you see this without getting an InvalidDocument exception please see htt
    p://api.mongodb.org/python/current/faq.html#does-pymongo-work-with-mod-wsgi
      continue_on_error, self.__uuid_subtype), safe)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
        "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
        exec code in run_globals
      File "D:\Office_Drive\RetailReco\contactsnew\rrpython\rcauto.py", line 28, in
    <module>
        rceval.AutoProcess()
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rrpython-0.1-py2.7.egg\rrpython\automizati
    on.py", line 67, in AutoProcess
        self._configdb[RCEVALPMTS].save(tempdict)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pymongo-2.5.1_-py2.7-win32.egg\pymongo\col
    lection.py", line 266, in save
        return self.insert(to_save, manipulate, safe, check_keys, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pymongo-2.5.1_-py2.7-win32.egg\pymongo\col
    lection.py", line 357, in insert
        continue_on_error, self.__uuid_subtype), safe)
    bson.errors.InvalidDocument: Cannot encode object: True
    
    "bson.errors.InvalidDocument: Cannot encode object: True"
```

When I using the "true" instance of True it works well, but it will insert a string value I want to add Boolean value, not a string.

When I trying to insert simple `{"name": True}`, it works well. How it is possible? What's going wrong?

Comment: Is this question still relevant for anybody author or voters?

Answer (score 1):

Going by the stack trace, `tempdict` is likely the value `True` rather than a dictionary of data to be inserted due to a problem elsewhere in the application (such as the rrpython library).

Answer (score -4):

That's simply because there is no such thing as `True` in json (or bson which is the format actually used in mongo, but they're closely related). Instead of manually changing this to a `'true'` string you can encode your document to json and then insert it to mongo:

```
import json
document = {u'Status': 'Active',
   u'Installation': {u'IsFrugal': True,  u'IsFeatureSet': True,  u'IsEvolving': True, 
   u'IsAffordable': True}, 
   u'AutoList': [u'IsFeatureSet', u'IsAffordable', u'IsFrugal'] 
}
jsonified_document = json.dumps(document)
```

Comment: there is `true` in JSON instead of `True` in Python, and pymongo do this conversion automatically